# Using Jasypt properties parser with Camel 3

Tags: apache-camel

We are migrating from Camel 2.x to Camel 3.4.4 and encountered an issue with Jasypt component.

In Camel 2 we used the following code for Jasypt properties parser:

```
        JasyptPropertiesParser jasypt = new JasyptPropertiesParser();
        jasypt.setPassword("...");
        PropertiesComponent pc = new PropertiesComponent();
        pc.setLocation("...");
        pc.setPropertiesParser(jasypt);
        context.addComponent("properties", pc);
```

In Camel 3 this no longer works, assumingly because `PropertiesComponent` was changed to `org.apache.camel.spi.PropertiesComponent`
and it no longer has the `setPropertiesParser` method.

Found no documentation about how to use Jasypt in Camel 3.

Help most appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: See the unit tests of the camel-jasypt component and/or its documentation page

Comment: Most appreciated, found it.